# Collection in model missing the data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this page which manages restaurants and reviews. I can create Restaurants and reviews perfectly, but when I want to link a review into a collection in the restaurant, this disapear when fetching it from the view

This is my restaurant model, where i want to storage the reviews of each restaurant:

```
public class Restaurant
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public float AverageRating { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

Review model:

```
public class Review
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string ReviewerName { get; set; }
    public int RestaurantID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
}
```

API Post:

```
public IActionResult Post(ReviewDTO r)
{
    try
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest("Not a valid model");
        else
        {
            Review review = _mapper.Map<ReviewDTO, Review>(r);
            //review.Restaurant = _restaurantAppService.Find(review.RestaurantID);
            _reviewAppService.Add(review);

            //_restaurantAppService.Find(review.RestaurantID).Reviews.Add(review);
            _restaurantAppService.Average(_restaurantAppService.Find(review.RestaurantID));
            return Ok();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log.Log.Error("Api error - Review - Post::" + ex.Message + "::" + ex.InnerException.Message + "::" + ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message);
        throw new Exception("Error Api - Review - Post \n", ex);
    }
}
```

And finally the repository:

```
public void Add(TEntity e)
{
    try
    {
        db.Set<TEntity>().Add(e);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error in Infra.DATA - Add" + ex.Message, ex);
    }
}

public IEnumerable<TEntity> All()
{
    try
    {
        return db.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking().ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error in Infra.DATA - All", ex);
    }
}
```

So here is the issue:

- The review is created
- The API call the application methods
- The entity class inserts the review into the database
- The api call the application method to insert the review into the restaurant list'reviews'
- The review is inserted successfully, debugging I can see that the restaurant is updated in the database with the review inserted
- The controller sends back the restaurant to see the details of the restaurant, where its reviews are listed, but in this
  step, the reviews are missing and it is set to null.

I can edit, delete and create a restaurant and a review, but I can't storage them with the restaurant.

I have done this very same project in framework instead of core and had no problem with it, anyone knows why is this happening?

Comment: Can you add the controller/service code where the restaurant is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're doing, since you haven't shown how you're actually getting the list of restaurants. However, I'm assuming you're using your `All()` method on your repository which is not actually a repository.

First and foremost, to your main issue. EF Core *never* automatically queries related entities. You must instruct it to do so via either eagerly, explicitly or lazy loading the relationship.

1. Eager loading is the preferred approach, as EF will issue a JOIN as you would expect and all the information will be returned in a single query. This necessitates using the `Include` method (which your "repository" has no functionality for). Regardless, that code would look something like:

   ```
   var restaurants = await _context.Restaurants.Include(x => x.Reviews).ToListAsync();
   ```
2. Explicit loading is worth noting, but it will be fairly uncommonly used. The only real benefit to this approach is being able to actually filter the related items that are returned, rather than just returning all of them.

   ```
   var reviews = await _context.Entry(restaurant).Collection(x => x.Reviews).LoadAsync();
   ```

   If you wanted to filter the reviews:

   ```
   var reviews = await _context.Entry(restaurant).Collection(x => x.Reviews).Query()
       .Where(x => x.Rating > 3)
       .ToListAsync();
   ```
3. Finally, there's lazy-loading. This is not recommended and should honestly be avoided. The way it works is that EF will dynamically derive a proxy class of your entity and override the getter on your collection property to request the related items from the context's object cache, or if they don't exist there, issue a query to fetch them. This then has the effect of essentially hiding the database query under the covers. You just interact with the related items, and EF magically goes and fetches them so that they're there. However, that is also the problem with this approach. It's far too easy too easy to hammer your database with queries without even realizing it. For example, if you iterate over all the restaurants and then access each collection reviews, you're issuing a query for each restaurant individually. The situation gets exponentially worse if you dig in multiple levels. Like let's say you had a foreign key to the user who wrote the review, and you then access that. You'd then be issuing a query per review per restaurant, which could easily amount to hundreds or even thousands of queries.

   Still, if you want to go this route, you need two things: 1) the collection property must be `virtual`, which it already is, and 2) you must explicitly turn it on:

   ```
   services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(o =>
       o.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"))
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies());
   ```

As I mentioned your "repository" is going to be problematic here. Your biggest problem is that repositories should actually return queryables (i.e. supports further alteration of the query before it's sent to the database). Instead, you're returning materialized lists (i.e. the query has already been sent). Then, going further, you shouldn't actually have a repository at all here, as EF already provides the unit of work and repository patterns. Having your own layer adds nothing but additional maintenance and testing concerns, making your app more brittle and harder to work with.

Comment: That was it! I had to override the All() Method but when using the Include it related the entity. I also changed the methods to they are querys, which makes more sense to be honest. Evrything works fine, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While using EF you can define the relationships in the OnModelCreating method of your database context or setup in your model classes. I advise setting up this relationships on the Models themselves for most cases expect for many to many relationship scenarios , since that is not your case you can do the following :

```
public class Review
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public string ReviewerName { get; set; }
        public int RestaurantID { get; set; }
        public DateTime Data { get; set; }

        public Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }
}
```

Now run the `dotnet ef add migration` command to generate the migration that will create the one to many relationship between Restaurant and Review

Comment: It is not necessary to add the navigation property here. It won't hurt, but it also won't fix the issue.

Comment: @ChrisPratt You are right. TIL that adding the Collection Navigation Property it will create the relationship.